# Navigating to a random page, using XDK

Tags: html, random, intel-xdk

I'm new to XDK, and I'm trying to figure out how to make a button navigate to a random page out of a set group of pages.  Is this a Javascript Math.random thing, and if so, how do I apply it to a button in XDK?  Any help or pointing to a resource would be helpful!  Thanks!

Update: So I've decided to instead have the button generate a random div on a new page. Here's the javascript:

```
window.onload=function() {
  var E = document.getElementsByClassName("item");
  var m = E.length;
  var n = parseInt(Math.random()*m);
  for (var i=m-1;i>=0;i--) {
      var e = E[i];
      e.style.display='none';
  }
  E[n].style.display='';
}
```

And here's the html on the new page:

```
<body>
<div class="item">One</div>
<div class="item">Two</div>
<div class="item">Three</div>
<div class="item">Four</div>
<div class="item">Five</div>
<div class="item">Six</div>
</body>
```

The initial load randomizes the div, but the when i go back to the main page and click the button again, it doesn't randomize again.  I know the problem is the window.onload, but I'm not sure how to fix it. How do I get the button to reload the array?

Comment: Where does the list of pages reside, in an array?
Can you provide some example of your code.

Comment: The technique you use to select a random item or page is the same as you would use in a web browser page, there is nothing about the XDK that controls how you navigate. The XDK only provides you with a way to run a pure web app (HTML/CSS/JS) in a web view, rather than in a browser -- and adds the Cordova and Intel XDK APIs to that context.